# Finding last column and then finding the last row in that column

Tags: excel, vba, range, excel-2010

I need to find the last column in a worksheet and then find the last row in that particular column. For last column I am using this:

```
lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
last_row = Range((Cells(Rows.count), lastcol).Find("*", after:=r, LookIn:=x1values, lookat:=x1part, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FALd5.png) is snapshot of the worksheet:

[image]

Can some also help me with putting all the data I want to save in an array 2 dimensional and then pasting the data on a Excel sheet?

Comment: here you can find some code to find last rows/columns http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how:

```
lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, lastcol).End(xlUp).Row

.Cells(lastrow + 1, lastcol).Resize(UBound(myarray)) = myarray
```

.

Let's assume the batch data are sourced in Sheet1 beginning in cell A1, here is how to make the 2D array:

```
Dim myarray

myarray = Sheet1.[a1].CurrentRegion
```

Comment: Hi Excel Hero, Thanks for the reply. I tried the same earlier was not working but now worked. I wonder what I have done wrong?

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing the full code that was not working. Could have just been a typo.

Comment: Hi Excel Hero, 
Thanks for the reply.    
                                                                                                              Arrays pro? I have multiple batches of data that is saved in different worksheets. what Iwant to do is that presently I am calculating the Subtotal(average) of the all the visible data from a filtered range. And I want to save that data in an Array (2, D). Once the data is completely saved for one batch. I want to copy the data to an excel sheet. And then do the same for the next Batch. thanks in advance. aj

Comment: The code is too big add here. I am new to the form and I do not know how I can add the complete code and the excel sheet.