# EXCEL-VBA column max

Tags: excel, vba

What would the equivalent to this be for the horizontal/colum?

```
v = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
```

I am guessing this but do not know how to check

```
v = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("zz1").End(xlRight).column
```

I am basically trying to figure out the how many columns there are.
I tried what I guessed but it is wrong

Comment: `xlRight` should be `xlToLeft`

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of one of these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33545516/finding-last-column-and-then-finding-the-last-row-in-that-column http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926972/excel-vba-finding-the-last-column-with-data http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17730639/how-to-find-and-select-the-last-column-in-vba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the index of the last column in the sheet, use
`Cells(1,Columns.Count).Column`

To get the last used Column, it is very similar.

```
Cells(1,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Comment: make sure you qualify the range object with the sheet. `Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1,Sheets("Sheet2").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

Comment: True, if the sheet to check the columns is not the active sheet. If it is, qualifying it is not necessary.

Comment: Would this work as well for rows?

Comment: You can use what you had above for rows. `Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Very important: this works only if all rows have the same number of columns, otherwise it simply returns the number of columns in row 1.
Replace the index **1** by the index of the longest row, or by the index of a specific row you want to check